# My application is not opening in the Android studio when I write this code in context.xml

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to make a layout with an image, then a scroll view text, and then again an image, but when I am running this content_main.xml then my application is not opening.

```
              <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
                <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                    android:id="@+id/context_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                    tools:context="com.example.hsports.myapplication.MainActivity"
                    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">
```

the following is the code for image which I want to place in the above section of app

```
                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView"
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="150dp"
                        android:layout_above="@+id/scrollView"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/shikher"

                        />
```

The following is the code to add a scroll view text in the middle of the app

```
                    <ScrollView
                        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="116dp"
                        android:layout_above="@+id/photo"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
                        >
```

This the Plain text which is inserted between the scroll view tags and under which we can scroll the huge text.

```
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/usedtext" />


                    </ScrollView>
```

the following is the code to add the image at last and view it below the scroll view text

```
                        android:layout_above="@+id/scrollView"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:src="@drawable/shikher"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"


                        />


                </RelativeLayout>
```

After when this code is executed and I try to open the application then its showing that the application cannot be opened.

Comment: post your logcast please !

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are trying to get a reference to ScrollView from ImageView:

```
            android:layout_above="@+id/scrollView"
```

before scrollview is created in the layout. Remove the line and try again.